# Mvn repository - changing description

Tags: java, mvn-repo

I have a public artifact in mvnrepository.com, and I need to add an important annotation like the date until I'm gonna do the maintenance of it.
Is there any way to add or change a description of the artifact itself? I'm not an expert with Java but I guess there should be a way through the pom file, but I didn't find any way to do that.

For instance, for PHP I can add this info in the composer.json description and then this annotation will be added in Packagist.

Could you please help me? I did a lot of research but I didn't find anything.

Thanks :)

Comment: You say you have a "repository", but [there are only 20 repos in total in there](https://mvnrepository.com/repos) and they are mostly owned by big companies. I suspect you don't mean 'repo', because you refer to a POM file and a POM file would belong to a specific artifact, not an entire repo. Can you clarify what you actually mean?

Comment: Yes, I meant the artifact ;)

Comment: Is there a possibility to add something like
<description>The maven project description</description> in the pom file
and then I will find this description as annotation in the artifact?

Comment: Maven POM [has a <description> tag](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html). It does appear like this website will use that information (e.g. if you look at [this Spring project](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test), the description starts "Starter for testing..." and the same can be found [in their POM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.5.5/spring-boot-starter-test-2.5.5.pom)). I don't see any documentation on the website to that effect though. ... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) The owner has his Twitter profile linked on the website, and there's an email address too. If you wanted a definitive answer, you could just ask him.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael :)